# All Microsoft store apps are hanging or crashing few times then resetting by itself, so how to mass reset all Microsoft store apps?

Tags: crash, reset, microsoft-store

(Windows 10 Home)

All Microsoft store apps are hanging or crashing few times then resetting by itself.I used Troubleshoot Microsoft store apps, it shows to reset all troubled apps but how can to reset all apps?

Apps include alarm &clock, app installer,weather ,calculator.......anything installed or can be updated using Microsoft Store are hanging or crashing few times.

**I want to reset them all but how to do it without resetting them one by one?**

EDIT:
After running **Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}**

i get this result seen in image.[image: Result of running thepowershell command]

Comment: Have you seen [Fix problems with apps from Microsoft Store](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4027498/microsoft-store-fix-problems-with-apps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible solutions:

- **Run Windows Store Apps Troubleshooter**
  Run Windows
  *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Store Apps >
  Run the troubleshooter*
  and follow on-screen directions.
- **Reset the Windows Store**
  Run Windows *Settings > Apps > Apps & features*, locate the Microsoft Store entry
  and click on it, click *Advanced options* and under "Reset", click the *Reset* button
  to should reinstall the Store with default values.
- **Re-register all apps**
  Open an elevated Windows PowerShell and run the following command

  ```
  Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
  ```

If none of the above helps, try to repeat these three operations while
[booting into Safe Mode with Networking](https://support.shaw.ca/t5/internet-articles/how-to-boot-your-computer-in-safe-mode-with-networking-windows/ta-p/5450#Windows10).

If you are still encountering problems:
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
Ensure you have good backups before starting.

Comment: i have made edit in question

Comment: Your problems seem more serious than I thought. I added some more steps.